# How to read extended events .xel file

Tags: sql-server

I have a certain request to read/parse the .xel file which is extended events file , How can I do this effectively and efficiently . One of my colleague advised to use API to parse the file , However I believe there should be a way that this can be achieved through SQL code itself . Help is much appreciated .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To read .xel files, you can use [sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-xe-file-target-read-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. For example:

```
select cast(event_data as XML) as event_data
from sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('D:\Folder\MySession*.xel', null, null, null)
```

Further you may want to parse the returned XML to get the data in table format. To do this, you need to decide what data to extract from the XML and write the appropriate XPath expressions. For example:

```
-- You have to know element names and their data types
select
    n.value('(@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as event_name,
    n.value('(@package)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS package_name,
    n.value('(@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2') AS [utc_timestamp],
    n.value('(data[@name="duration"]/value)[1]', 'int') as duration,
    n.value('(data[@name="cpu_time"]/value)[1]', 'int') as cpu,
    n.value('(data[@name="physical_reads"]/value)[1]', 'int') as physical_reads,
    n.value('(data[@name="logical_reads"]/value)[1]', 'int') as logical_reads,
    n.value('(data[@name="writes"]/value)[1]', 'int') as writes,
    n.value('(data[@name="row_count"]/value)[1]', 'int') as row_count,
    n.value('(data[@name="last_row_count"]/value)[1]', 'int') as last_row_count,
    n.value('(data[@name="line_number"]/value)[1]', 'int') as line_number,
    n.value('(data[@name="offset"]/value)[1]', 'int') as offset,
    n.value('(data[@name="offset_end"]/value)[1]', 'int') as offset_end,
    n.value('(data[@name="statement"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as statement,
    n.value('(action[@name="database_name"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') as database_name
from (select cast(event_data as XML) as event_data
from sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('D:\Folder\MySession*.xel', null, null, null)) ed
cross apply ed.event_data.nodes('event') as q(n)
```

Comment: This sufficed the need . And are these the only fields we have for extended events ? If I need the query plan to be included , How can I do that ?

Comment: No, these fields are just an example. You should read the data, that is captured from your session. First look at the xml read from the file, then construct appropriate XPath queries to transform it to table (if you need this). There are thousands of things that you can capture with XE, but this isn't related to the "how to read .xel file" question. You can only read what is written in the file, obviously.

Comment: I did some investigation on this and now I am able to modify the XPath queries to get what I need for a given specific scenario / requirement . Your comments and answers helped a lot to dive in . This was really helpful

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful! It will be very appreciated if you accept and upvote my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had an XEL file from the Auditing system on Azure SQL Database, so I found this post. But it would not run with fn_xe_file_target_read_file, so I had to use fn_get_audit_file like this

```
select * from sys.fn_get_audit_file('c:\temp\08_11_22_921_16*.xel', null, null)
```