# How to read SQL server logs (XEL) files in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-spark, azure-sql-database

I am trying to process the SQL server log file (XEL) in Java and convert into other format like JSON. I am not able to find any documentation on How to read XEL files and there are no library that can be used to read the XEL file.

Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can [select data from E**x**pression **E**ncoding **L**og files in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53147992/how-to-read-extended-events-xel-file/53149767) and fetch the results in Java (JDBC or anything), but I don't know a parser library or anything ready to use in Java.

Comment: @deHaar that doesnt seems to work if the xel file stored in Azure blob. Do you have any reference for that ?, how to do the authentication to Azure blob through JDBC ?

Comment: @deHaar also fails if i download the file and try the query with error `SQL Error [40538] [S0003]: A valid URL beginning with 'https://' is required as value for any filepath specified
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, I tried to search for a library to parse XEL format file in Java, but failed. I think a workaround solution to satisfy your needs may should be considered by you.

Here is some workaround solutions in my mind.

1. There are some tools to help parsing XEL format file, such as [`Log Parser 2.2`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) and [`Read-DbaXEFile`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Read-DbaXEFile) function of PowerShell Module [`sqlcollaborative/dbatools`](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools). For `Log Parser 2.2` usage, please refer to the blogs [How to parse SQL Server Error Log with Log Parser 2.2](https://blog.sqlterritory.com/2017/11/07/parse-error-log-with-log-parser-2-2/) and [Microsoft’s Log Parser Utility: Swell ETL](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-tools/microsofts-log-parser-utility-swell-etl/). For function `Read-DbaXEFile`, please see its source code https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/master/functions/Read-DbaXEFile.ps1.
2. There is a nuget package named [`XELite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.XELite/) in C#, which be cross platform library to read XEvents from XEL files or live SQL streams.

Considering for your scenario, I think you can try to the two workaround solution to parse XEL format files stored in Azure Storage first within Azure Functions in [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio) or [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-powershell) with [Blob Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function), or within Azure Data Factory with a [Custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity), to extract these data what you want for further data processing in Spark.

Comment: thanks for the pointers. We have tried few of those options already but the problem is it is not getting well integrated with our existing Spark clusters or java based solutions.